# Driver for ATI Mobility radeon HD 560v

Tags: laptop, drivers, ati-mobility-radeon

My laptop (Dell Studio Notebook 1747) came drivers preinstalled for Win 7 (64-bit) drivers.
now I want to update drivers using ATI installer.
but I cannot find any driver for this card in ATI site.

Any tips?

Comment: Which laptop ? Model ?

Comment: Dell Studio Notebook 1747

Comment: This looks interesting...http://www.downloadatoz.com/driver/articles/ati-mobility-radeon-hd-4570-4650-560v-graphics-driver-for-dell-laptops.html - don't necessarily recommend/trust the site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't the drivers included in the Catalyst suite?

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx#1

That is meant for the 5xxx series, if that is not what you're looking for then, according to AMD/ATI, the drivers supplied by the notebook manufacturer are the ones that must be used as they are specific to the display type.

> Advisory:
>   The display driver supplied by the laptop manufacturer is customized for the built-in flat panel display, and the graphics features and functions specific to the laptop. It is strongly recommended to use the supplied drivers.

Answer (score 1):

From [ATI](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-560v/Pages/hd-560v-overview.aspx)'s website:

> NOTE: The ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 500v
>   series GPUs are based on the
>   award-winning architecture of the ATI
>   Mobility Radeon™ HD 4000 series,
>   DirectX® 10.1-capable GPUs.

The Drivers link on the above linked page does not list any Win7-64bit drivers for the HD 500 series card, however, if it is based on the HD 4000 series tech then you may be able to use the [HD 4000 series drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx) for Win7-64bit

You could also check the website for the laptop manufacturer.